# Custom TextView with TextAppearance cannot have textColor overridden in XML

Tags: android, textview, android-resources, android-styles, android-color

I'm trying to create a custom implementation of `TextView` that can be used to encapsulate all of the desired attributes of the text to be displayed.

What I've managed to do so far is:

- Apply a custom font.
- Apply a `TextAppearance` which includes things like `letterSpacing` and `textColor`.

This works as expected **but** when I try to change the colour of the text in XML the new text colour is completely ignored and the colour of the text remains the default that I've setup in the `TextAppearance`. It appears that the `TextAppearance` overrides the properties of the `TextView` provided in XML.

**Question:**

How do I create a custom `TextView` with default properties that can be modified in XML (mainly `textColor`)? Consider that this custom `TextView` exists in a **separate module** from the project it'll be used in.

Code:

*CustomTextView*

```
public class MyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    setTextAppearance(context, R.style.MyText);
    setTypeface(FontCache.futuraBookReg(getContext()));
   }
}
```

*Style*

```
<style name="MyText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_colour_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.04</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">8sp</item>
</style>
```

*FontCache* (Included for completeness. Issue persists even without custom fonts)

```
class FontCache {

private static final String MY_FONT = "font/my_font.ttf";

private static Map<String, Typeface> fontMap = new HashMap<>();

static Typeface myFont(Context context) {
    return getFont(context, MY_FONT);
}

private static Typeface getFont(Context context, String fontName) {
    if (fontMap.containsKey(fontName)) {
        return fontMap.get(fontName);
    } else {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontName);
        fontMap.put(fontName, tf);
        return tf;
    }
   }
}
```

*Attempt to colour TextView in XML*

```
<com.example.text.MyText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/new_text_colour"
        android:text="Hello" />
```

Comment: you have to set style to your textview in xml

Comment: The `setTextAppearance()` call you have in your `init()` method is overriding all the values set from the `AttributeSet` that were applied in the `super` constructor.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I agree. Any idea how I can set these text properties (via `TextAppearance` or otherwise) while maintaining those set in the `AttributeSet`?

Comment: You can set the `textAppearance` in the layout XML instead - `android:textAppearance="@style/MyText"` - as that will be applied before any of the other individual appearance attributes.

Comment: @MikeM. What I'm hoping to achieve is to have all of these attributes 'built in' to the actual `TextView`. I don't want to have to use a `TextAppearance` each time I use this `TextView`. I want the text to render as expected based on the attributes in the `TextAppearance` or by applying a style somehow.

Comment: You can setup a default style attribute for your custom `TextView`. I'm not sure if this is what you have in mind, as far as "built in", so I threw a quick example on Drive first: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yCxiylEdYkRTR1T2IzZnYwZHc/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks - though this would require me to rely on the project that uses the library with the custom `TextView`s to set the default style attribute in its theme. I want this library to work without prior setup wherever it's used.

Comment: You can package a default style resource in the library. The Android support libraries do this all the time.

Comment: @MikeM. Perfect. The above approach works. Do you wanna provide an answer and I accept it? If not; I'm happy to do it myself.

Comment: Will do. I'm mobile, atm, but I'll get one posted when I get to my desk later this evening. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Aw, jeez, I completely forgot about this. Sorry 'bout that. Feel free to post your answer.